# Displaying RichText in Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports, richtext

I have a report created in Crystal (the version that comes with Visual Studio 2005) that contains an IFieldObject that I want to use to display some rich text.  I have set the TextFormat of the IFieldObject to crRTFText, however when I run the report the textbox displays all the rtf markup rather than actually displaying the formatted text.

Is there some other settings that need to be changed in order for Crystal to display rich text?

Comment: You may not have all of the rtf markup that is needed to make this display correctly. I am not an rtf markup expert, but I may be able to help. Can you post the field value and perhaps I can help you modify it so that the rtf displays?

Answer (score 1):

What viewer are you using for your report?   The HTML based viewers (WebForm and Java) may not support RTF output.

The ActiveX (definitely!) or WinForm (I think) viewers should support RTF in fields.

Have you tried rich formatting with html instead?